# Find out what numbers are not in sequential order

Tags: excel, numbers

I have a list of numbers, ranging from 100000 to 101000 and i need to find which ones are not in order, is there anyway to do this ? As i dont want to go through a list of 1000 numbers

PS. I am taking this data from SQL So in this instance i cannot sort the data. I just need to know which are not in correct order

Comment: If they are in a column from A1 to A1001 you could write this in B2: `=A1<A2` and copy it down to end of your data set. Then you can put a filter on top and check if all returned TRUE.

Comment: I have ammended my post @pnuts, i cant sort it, i have to find out what is out of place

Comment: Do you absolutely need to see which ones are out of order in excel or would a select query in SQL also suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your numbers start in A1 then:

```
=IF(SMALL(A:A,ROW())=A1,"")
```

in Row1 and copied down should indicate those that are out of order.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the number in the SQL entry you can sort it directly when writing the query using ORDER BY in your SQL statement

Comment: I need to know which are out of order, so this would not help

Comment: I'm not aware of any excel function that would do this. Its hard to say since I don't know how the data is formatted (maybe get it to columns or you might need to write a script)